# Ladder against a wall in equilibrium, why the normal upward force needs to be equal to the wheight force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, statics

At first I didn't get how how the resulting reaction forces where generated, so I made a thought experiment, which has some flaw which I cannot understand.
Imagine you have a uniform ladder resting at an angle to a frictionless wall, resting in a surface with some friction.
Initially the only force acting is the weight force, acting on the center of mass, if we think of the point of contact as a a rotation pole then we have a torque.

[image]

Now suppose we decompose the weight force vector in his parallel and normal to the ladder components

[image]

The parallel component doesn't contribute to the torque since the scalar product is zero.
So the only component that we need to consider is the normal one.
From here I might be completely off track but I want to give a try to explain my point.
Now since the only contribute is the parallel one to the torque it must bu even on all the ladder in particular in the point of contact with the wall.

[image]

Now decomponing the response from the wall we get a response in the y axis and a response on the x axis, which is countered by the friction of the surface.
And should get the usual diagram of forces

[image]

Now I know I got wrong somewhere because for example I'm completely ignoring the parallel wheight force component but where ?
The other thing is that actually this model takes into consideration the fact that some of the wheight is offloaded to the wall, this shouldn't be accounted in the dynamics formula if
we require that the Response from the wall on the y axis is equal to the weight force.
This last point is kind of proved by some rudimentary experiments I did

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... some of the weight is offloaded to the wall ...

I think this is where your misunderstanding lies. If the wall is vertical then the normal force from the wall, which is always perpendicular to the wall, is horizontal. If the wall is also frictionless (which you assume at the beginning of your example) then the wall does not exert any vertical force on the ladder.

If the ladder is in equilibrium resting against a vertical, frictionless wall then the normal force from the ground is equal and opposite to the weight of the ladder (since these are the only two vertical forces acting on the ladder) and the normal force from the  wall is equal and opposite to the friction force from the ground (since these are the only two horizontal forces acting on the ladder).